# C++11 non-const constexpr func with template: OK, without template: error

Tags: templates, c++11

I use g++ 4.8.1.
Compile:
g++ -std=c++11 test23.cpp test24.cpp -o a

---

test24.cpp:

```
int gi1=98;
```

---

test23.cpp:

```
extern int gi1;   // compiler cannot predict the value

template<class T>
constexpr bool f8() {
   return (gi1 > 5);
}

// constexpr bool ce = f8<float>();  // OK, it is compile error

int main() {
  bool bz1 = f8<float>();
}
```

---

Compiles without error. Shouldn't it be error ?
Now without template:

---

test23.cpp:

```
extern int gi1;

constexpr bool f8() {
   return gi1 > 5;
}

int main() {
  bool bz1 = f8();
}
```

---

OK, Compile error:
test23.cpp:4:1: error: the value of ‘gi1’ is not usable in a constant expression
test23.cpp:1:12: note: ‘int gi1’ is not const

---

Thank you in advance

Comment: ...possible compiler bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it helps understanding, demonstrating this problem doesn't require an `extern` variable defined in another translation unit. Anything that may not appear in a constant expression is sufficient:

```
int i = 42;
// neither const nor constexpr
// lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of it may not appear in a constant expression

constexpr int j = i; // error

template<class T>
constexpr int func_templ() { return i; }
constexpr int func      () { return i; }  // error

int main() {
    // constexpr int rest = func_templ<void>();  // OK, it is compile error
    int result = func_templ<void>();
        result = func();
}
```

The function `func` itself makes the program ill-formed because of [dcl.constexpr]/5:

> For a `constexpr` function, if no function argument values exist such that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

A `constexpr` function is **not** required to contain only constant expressions. But in this case, it always yields a non-constant-expression. Therefore the program is ill-formed. For the function template `func_temp`, it's the same problem. However, g++ and clang++ don't produce a diagnostic message. Maybe because name lookup is more complicated for templates, even if it is an ordinary non-dependent lookup in this case.

To demonstrate the error, here's a version that compiles fine:

```
int i = 42;

constexpr int func(bool p)
{ return p ? 42 : i; }

int main() {
      constexpr int result0 = func(true);   // works
    //constexpr int result1 = func(false);  // error
                int result2 = func(false);  // works
}
```

Comment: Yes, for `result0` the `i` in `func` is actually not evaluated and 42 is returned. If `i` was evaluated compile error would occur.